# How write performance can be improved for RecordWriter

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, mapr

Can anyone help me out finding correct API to improve write performance?

We use `MultipleOutputs<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>` class to write data we read from a table, we use the newly created file as a backup. We face performance issue in write using `MultipleOutputs`, it takes nearly 5 seconds for every 10000 records we write.

This is the code we use:

```
  Result[]  results = // result from another table
  MultipleOutputs<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>  mos = new MultipleOutputs<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> ();
  for(Result res : results ){
    mos.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(result.getRow()), result, baseoutputpath);
  }
```

We get a batch of 10000 rows and write them in a loop, with `baseoutputpath` changing depending on `Result` content.

We are facing performance dip when writing into `MultipleOutputs`, we suspect that it might be due to writing in a loop.

Is there any other API in maprdb or HBase which push data to database using fewer RPC calls by buffering upto certain limit.

We write data as records so no file system write class would work for us.

Please note that we use mapreduce job to do all of the above.

Comment: is that your reduce code?

Comment: No , we don't set any reducer , we just use mapper and write into file